# I am getting 'Permission denied' every time when a mail is send

Tags: magento-1.9, email

I have my Magento 1.9 installed on CentOS 6.6 locally and every time I send a mail I get permission denied. Same mail settings works perfectly fine on Production (AWS).
I tried on different installation on same system all are giving same error.

Comment: permission change in :-http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html

Comment: visit link:-http://magentoexpertforum.com/showthread.php/13470-Problem-with-sending-emails-SMTP-not-working